# Sorting alphanumeric dates in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a data set were a column represents the expiry date of a product in the following format: 1M, 2M, 1Y, 2Y, 1W, 2W, 1D, 2D. I would like to sort my data based on these dates in Excel, but I'm doing it in a very inefficient way, by expressing everything in days and then sorting the data according to the Days_column I create. Is there a better way to deal with this kind of data?
[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of a date?

Comment: Are we doing this with built in excel functions or vba ?

Comment: For example, I have a dataset containing five products I bought on 2015/03/01 and their expiry dates are: 1M, 2M, 1Y, 3D, 2W. I would like to sort the products I bought based on the expiry date.

Comment: @HolmesIV I'm using built in excel functions.

Comment: Easiest way is probably great 2 tables, one of data and one of possible codes to look ups. In the table with dates, codes, add index match on the code table to translate 2M=  60. Then add a fourth to Simply add column 3, to column 1 (date) then sort. copy and paste values if you have tons of data.

Comment: @HolmesIV I don't get it :-) Any simpler way to do it even by using SQL?

Comment: You could do the same thing, I mean how many Codes are there? script out an insert to #temp in SQL then left join, Dateadd(dd, codedays ) and sort.*Change* could be inner join if you have all possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have this understood. Here is a picture of the final result:
[image]

I found some good information here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-subtract-dates-b83768f5-f695-4311-98b1-757345f7e926#bm6

I put this in D2 and copied it down: `=LEFT(C2,LEN(C2)-1)`.  In cell E2 I put `=RIGHT(C2,1)`, and copied it all the way down. In F2 I have `=IF(E2="Y",DATE(YEAR(A2)+D2,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)),IF(E2="M",EDATE(A2,D2),IF(E2="D",A2+D2,IF(E2="W",A2+(D2*7),"x"))))`.

Notes: Adding months is based on the number of days in the upcoming months, and not always equal to 30. Notice that 1 month added to 1/31/2016 puts you at 2/29/2016.  Adding the year works the same way, you don't have to worry about leap years messing you up.

For weeks I used the number of weeks multiplied by 7, and then just added those days to the Buying date.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your expiry into two columns - `Expiry_number` i.e. the duration or numeric part of the expiry, and `Expiry_unit` i.e. M, D, Y. You can split this using functions, for example your numeric column:

```
=LEFT(D3, LEN(D3)-1)
```

where `D3` is the expiry. And then your units column:

```
=Right(D3, 1)
```

Then you can sort the the data on two levels - alphabetically on the `Expiry_unit` (as chance would have it the durations units increase in length alphabetically D, M, Y) and then numerically on `Expiry_number`.